# Django view didn't return an HttpResponse object

Tags: python, ajax, django

I'm having an issue with getting ajax to work with my django view. The exact error is

> `CustomMembers.decorators.formquestioninfo` didn't return an
>   `HttpResponse` object. It returned `None` instead.

The view is limited by a custom decorator which is the following.

```
def is_god_admin(f):
    def wrap(request, *args, **kwargs):
        # This checks to see if the user is a god admin. If they are not, they get thrown to their profile page
        if 'userID' not in request.session.keys() and 'username' not in request.session.keys():
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/Members/Login")
        else:
            # lets check the roleID to what ID we need.
            god_admin = Roles.objects.get(role_name='System Admin')
            if request.session['roleID'] != god_admin.id:
                return HttpResponseRedirect("/Members/Profile/" + request.session['userID'])
            return f(request, *args, **kwargs)

    wrap.__doc__ = f.__doc__
    wrap.__name__ = f.__name__
    return wrap
```

The view right now only contains a return to show the template along with a check if ajax was used to post a request.

View

```
@is_god_admin
def formquestionsinfo(request, formid, catid, mainid):
    """ Displays the forms information."""
    # need the following values in both post and get methods

    forms = Form.objects.all()

    if request.is_ajax():
        print('ajax request') # this fires then errors
    else:
        return render(request, formquestions.html, 'forms':forms) # this works just fine with a get request
```

The ajax code that is being executes is: (the getCookie is based off of django documentation - [Cross Site Request Forgery protection](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/csrf/#ajax)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
                $("#{{main_id}}_main_visible").click(function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var url = window.location.href;
                    $.ajax({
                      type:'get',
                      headers: {"X-CSRFToken": getCookie("csrftoken")},
                      url: url,
                      data: { mainid: {{main_id}} },
                      async: true,
                      cache: false
                    });
                });
            });
```

All help is really appreciated. Thanks gain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`return f(request, *args, **kwargs)` calls the view function in the wrapper of the decorator. However, the branch for ajax requests only does a `print` and leaves the function without a `return` statement that *returns* a valid response object:

```
if request.is_ajax():
    print('ajax request') 
    ... # return a response object here to avoid returning None
```

Comment: So even though I'm asking jquery/ajax not to reload the page, django still needs to do a return to render the template?

Comment: Every request must go a with valid response. None is not a valid response.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and your time. It is now working.

Comment: @MosesKoledoye, may I ask you to have a look at a related question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50671066/python-django-ajax-valueerror-the-view-khobor-views-show-recommendation-didn ?